# ADFS signout issue on SharePoint site in IE & Edge browser

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, adfs

We have configured SharePoint with Active Directory ADFS authentication. We have implemented a sign out button that redirects users to
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TenantID]/wsfed?wa=wsignout1.0.  However, the users are able to log back in without requiring to enter their credentials again.  This happens even when we close the browser.  I understand this is an expected behavior when we access the site from inside the domain network because the new sign-on automatically takes place. However, we don't expect this to happen when we access the site from an external network.

The behavior happens only on IE 11 and Edge. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox where users will be required to enter their credentials to log back in. However, I found a work around to make it work on IE as listed below.

1. Sign in on the SharePoint home page.
2. Clear browser cache manually
3. Click sign out to redirect on https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TenantID]/wsfed?wa=wsignout1.0
4. Re-enter the URL and you will be prompted to enter credentials as expected.

Does anyone know the reason behind this behavior? And a possibly a fix too?

Comment: I would probably first attempt to look at the traffic with Fiddler.  When you signout from ADFS, it should issue a GET to your SharePoint site with the querystring ?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 and the response should clear the FedAuthX cookies.  Does this occur?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked Fiddler logs and it does issue a /login.srf?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 on both Internet explorer and Chrome. However, Chrome prompts for entering credentials when I try to relogin. But IE allows me to login seamlessly which should not happen.

Comment: In Fiddler, does the response from /login.srf?wa=signoutcleanup1.0 clear the FedAuthX cookie(s)?